# How to handle directory paths in Makefile directive

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile directive defined as follows:
`OBJ = $(SRC:%.c=$(BUILDDIR)/%.o)`
where `$SRC` is defined as
`file1.c file2.c` etc.
.
This works just fine when all files are at the same level as the makefile.
If they are in a directory i.e `./src/file1.c ./src/file2.c` it does not.
It fails because it tries to append the source path to the build path i.e
`gcc -o ./build/./src/file1.o src/file.c`
.
I tried to use the `nodir` keyword but no luck.
I'm looking for the build command to look like this
`gcc -o ./build/file1.o ./src/file.c` 
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Try `notdir`. There is no `nodir`.

Comment: That was a typo . I did try notdir like so 
```OBJ = $(notdir $(SRC):%.c=$(BUILDDIR)/%.o)``` 
Got the following error:
Considering target file `file1.c'.
       File `file1.c' does not exist.
       Finished prerequisites of target file `file1.c`
      Must remake target `file1.c'.
make: *** No rule to make target `file1.c', needed by `apps'.  Stop.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try an experiment:

```
SRC = ./src/file1.c ./src/file2.c
OBJ = $(notdir $(SRC):%.c=$(BUILDDIR)/%.o)

apps: $(OBJ)
```

We get:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `file1.c', needed by `apps'.  Stop.
```

Something's amiss here. Let's look at `OBJ`:

```
$(info $(OBJ))
```

We get:

```
file1.c %.o
```

Yikes! We constructed `OBJ` incorrectly. What if we break it up into smaller steps?

```
SIMPLE_SRC = $(notdir $(SRC))
OBJ = $(SIMPLE_SRC:%.c=$(BUILDDIR)/%.o)
$(info $(OBJ))
```

We get:

```
./build/file1.o ./build/file2.o
```

It turns out that [substitution references](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs) of the form `$(var:%a=%b)` do not allow us to put functions in the `var`. At this point we should probably  forgo them and write the full [pattern substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions):

```
OBJ = $(patsubst %.c,$(BUILDDIR)/%.o,$(notdir $(SRC)))
$(info $(OBJ))
```

We get:

```
./build/file1.o ./build/file2.o
```

Comment: While the path for the object file is now correct I still get an error unfortunately..
 Considering target file `/home/andy/project/build/file1.o'.
       File `/home/andy/project/build/file1.o' does not exist.
       Finished prerequisites of target file `/home/andy/project/build/file1.o'.
      Must remake target `/home/andy/project/build/file1.o'.
make: *** No rule to make target `/home/andy/project/build/file1.o', needed by `apps'.  Stop.

Comment: @user2233677: How much of this problem do you know how to solve? Can you write a pattern rule that will allow Make to build `build/file1.o` if `src/file1.c` exists?

Comment: I am stumped at the moment. Any help is appreciated

Comment: @user2233677: You must start with basic tutorials and simple makefiles, and work up. Always be sure that your makefile works perfectly before you try a more complex example; *never add to code that doesn't work.*

Comment: That is a very helpful comment. Especially the last part. I would've never figured it out on my own. Thank you so much